# firefox aliased/jagged fonts in xfce

Tags: firefox, fonts, kde, xfce, anti-aliasing

I've been using linux mint 7 for a couple of weeks now and I'm pretty happy with it, but I wanted to try out other desktops, e.g. KDE/Xfce

I'm not sure if it's KDE's fault of Xfce's, but firefox's font rendering sucks now, it renders jagged/aliased fonts.

I'm using xfce right now,

My `Xfce settings Manager > appearance > fonts` settings roughly look like this:

```
Default Font:

     Sans | 9  

Rendring :

 [x] Enable anti-aliasing  

           Hinting: None  
   Sub-pixel Order: None
```

But it's as if firefox ignores these settings!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try editing your `.fonts.conf` file under your home directory (`~/.fonts.conf`).

This works well for me:

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
 <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
 <fontconfig>
  <match target="font" >
   <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </edit>
  </match>
 </fontconfig>
```

Comment: Yeah, I find fonts.conf sort of overrides pretty much everything else, so I always look to it first for font problems. Glad it helped!

Comment: Careful, there is a space in the code above, make sure there is no space before the first opening bracket (check if you get `Fontconfig error: "~/.fonts.conf", line 1: XML or text declaration not at start of entity` error on running `fc-cache` after adding this file).